# How do i create a power bi sever. where the data is hosted in premise server not on cloud

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I have heard that without use of premium we can host power bi dashboard in server. For a 6 month trail period (i heard for am a guy that knows a guy). Can we implement that if yes someone please explain me

I am expecting to share BI dashboard internally within the organization.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install [Power BI Report Server](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/report-server/) to host Power BI reports and Paginated Reports (RDL reports, like SSRS) on your own server.